# Make zsh tab completion like bash

Tags: bash, zsh, auto-complete

I don't have self-confidence in using term "completion". I just want to make zsh behavior like bash. (See uploaded gif)

[image: bash v.s. zsh]

As this gif image shows, bash can *complete* path of the file by pressing tab key, but zsh can't...

Is it possible to make zsh tab completion like bash?

Comment: I never fiddled with completion, but my zsh works in this way out of the box.  Could your problem be related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32075/zsh-takes-two-tabs-to-complete-filenames)  question?

Comment: @user1934428 Do you mean your out of box zsh works like my bash sample? Hum... That's funny... I think my issue is not related with the URL which you supplied.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly like you are showing. I'm running zsh 5.8.1 on MacOS. What happens if you press the TAB key in a zsh session, if it does not complete? Thinking of it: Could you try to **explicitly turn on** completion, by doing a `autoload -Uz compinit ; compinit  -i`?

Comment: BTW, just found this: If you run afterwards (i.e. after `compinit -i`) the command `bashcompinit`, zsh is supposed  to make zsh completion as close as possible as in bash. But this is necessary only, if you want to port your own bash completion scripts to zsh. As I said before, I just use the genuine zsh completion.

Comment: OK. Have tried your suggestion, but I can't get any good result.  I think my zsh have something wrong... I should use bash as login shell if I want to use *comfortable* completion. Thank you for your co-operation...

Comment: What terminal application do you use for running your shell? Perhaps the terminal is misconfigured and intercepts some keystrokes. From your screenshot, it could be Terminal.app or iTerm2. I would install the most recent zsh (using homebrew), then configure a terminal profile to run this zsh with the `-f` option (so that it bypasses most of your zsh startup files), and then try tab-completion (and describe HOW your zsh reacts to the tab, if it reacts at all).